# jQuery dataTables - initiate on page of specific value

Tags: jquery, datatables

I use the [Datatable Jquery plugin](http://datatables.net/) to represent a highscore of the users in a game. The users are sorted by their rank, and the DataTable handles pagination and shows 20 users per page. When a user is logged in and goes to the highscore, the datatable should automatically turn to the page where the current user is placed in the highscore. But the datatable loads page 1 by default. How can I make the DataTable turn to the page of the highscore where the logged in user is placed?

See picture of the datatable here: http://tinypic.com/r/i2mvyt/8

[image]

In this example, if the user is placed number 32, he will show up on page 4. But he will have to find that out himself. I want to make an implementation where the datatable finds the rank of the current user, and turns the page to where he is positioned.

Comment: Please provide some code and / or a fiddle demonstrating the problem. It is not so clear what you are asking for.

Comment: I've provided a more detailed explanation and a picture.

Comment: Thats great. I have inserted the image to the question.